# python sqlalchemy not filling in the row

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Hello I am new with SQLalchemy and have some problems with inserting data in a column.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine                            
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base                 
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Boolean     
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref                        
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Base = declarative_base()

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)

        def __init__(self, name, password, email):
            self._name = name
            self._password = password
            self._email = email    

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()


dm_user = Users("Dungeonmaster", "123", "email")
print dm_user.name
print dm_user.password
print dm_user.email

session.add(dm_user)

our_user = session.query(Users).filter_by(name='Dungeonmaster').first() 

session.commit()
```

I used sqlite studio to see if the data is added, and I see that a new row is being made (with a new id.) but the data name, password and email is not inserted.

With the print I see even before I try to add something goes wrong, but I don't know what. please help me out a bit

( dm_user = Users("Dungeonmaster", "123", "email") tried with single quotes as well (helped me before using sqlalchemy, but no difference here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init method does not initialize the persistent columns. Try instead (remove underscores):

```
def __init__(self, name, password, email):
    self.name = name
    self.password = password
    self.email = email
```

Comment: omg, so sorry, changed that later and seems i missed some. really feel silly I didn't see that haha. Thanks man